# Memory error when initializing Xception using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, keras, gpu

I am having difficulty implementing the pre-trained Xception model for binary classification over new set of classes. The model is successfully returned from the following function:

```
#adapted from:
#https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4465

from keras.applications.xception import Xception
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Model

def get_xception(in_shape,trn_conv):
  #Get back the convolutional part of Xception trained on ImageNet
  model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

  #Here the input images have been resized to 299x299x3, so this is the
  #same as Xception's native input
  input = Input(in_shape,name = 'image_input')

  #Use the generated model 
  output = model(input)

  #Only train the top fully connected layers (keep pre-trained feature extractors)
  for layer in model.layers:
      layer.trainable = False
  #Add the fully-connected layers 
  x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output)
  x = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
  x = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
  x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

  #Create your own model 
  my_model = Model(input=input, output=x)
  my_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD')

return my_model
```

This returns fine, however when I run this code:

```
model=get_xception(shp,trn_feat)
in_data=HDF5Matrix(str_trn,'/inputs')
labels=HDF5Matrix(str_trn,'/labels')
model.fit(in_data,labels,shuffle="batch")
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1576, in fit
  self._make_train_function()
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 960, in _make_train_function
  loss=self.total_loss)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 169, in get_updates
  v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 705, in _run_op
  return getattr(ops.Tensor, operator)(a._AsTensor(), *args)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 865, in binary_op_wrapper
  return func(x, y, name=name)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1088, in _mul_dispatch
  return gen_math_ops._mul(x, y, name=name)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1449, in _mul
  result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
  op_def=op_def)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
  original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/home/tsmith/.virtualenvs/keras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
  self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[204800,2048]
  [[Node: training/SGD/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](SGD/momentum/read, training/SGD/Variable/read)]]
```

I have been tracing the function calls for hours now and still can't figure out what is happening. The system should be far above and beyond the requirements. System specs:

```
Ubuntu Version: 14.04.5 LTS
Tensorflow Version: 1.3.0
Keras Version: 2.0.7
28x dual core Inten Xeon processor (1.2 GHz)
4x NVidia GeForce 1080 (8Gb memory each)
```

Any clues as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: So I figured out it has to do with the last 2 fully connected layers, but I need them to learn new classes.  I have also attempted replacing these lines:
  x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output)
  x = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
  x = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
  x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

with this
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(output)
  x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

Such that it is identical to the original Xception architecture, just with 2 class outputs. Still no luck.

Comment: Try a smaller batch size. Keras+TF is not so efficient on memory usage. The default `batch_size=32` in `fit()` seems to be too large for a 8GB GPU with `Xception`. I guess you have to lower it to 16 (or even 10).

Comment: Sorry for just now responding, I've been fairly absent from SO lately. That is exactly what I ended up doing and everything worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Per Yu-Yang, the simplest solution was to reduce the batch size, everything ran fine after that!